# How to refresh google map v3 on jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile, dictionary

I have a working jqm and phonegap mobile app, it uses sql to populate data locations using latitude and longitude.  My problem is that the map doesn't refresh, means it only shows the previously opened location.

The listview has `maplist` with data latitude and data longitude different for each list.  When a list is clicked it goes to the map page, passing the latitude and longitude values.  I also created a console.log so I can see that the passed values are correct, but the map only displaying the first previously passed values.

This is the click event:

```
$('.maplist').click(function() {
   lat = $(this).attr('data-lat'),
   long = $(this).attr('data-long');

   $.mobile.changePage('#maps');

   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
   $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': myLatlng});
}
```

on google map's wiki, it says that `$('#map_canvas').gmap('refresh');` whould fix the problem but I tried putting this line before and after the gmap to no avail.

How can I fix this problem?  Many thanks.